# XML Parent & child Attributes reading in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I have the following data in my XML file.

```
<main>
    <Team Name="Development"  ID="10">
        <Emp Source="Business" Total="130" Active="123" New="12"  />
        <Emp Source="Business" Total="131" Active="124" New="13" />
    </Team>
    <Team Name="Testing"  ID="10">
        <Emp Source="Business" Total="133" Active="125" New="14" />
    </Team>
</main>
```

I want to read above data  & store values into arrays,Can any one help on these?

Comment: -1 , why dont you just search your problem and follow tutorials. if you then get stuck, [SO] is there. 

for instance http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to convert those xml into Arrays, anyhow you can read xml and parse it by several ways. Normally we use DOM or Stax Parser and a [Tutorial link is here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html), also here is a [Java SAX Parsing Example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html) tutorial.

Hope this can help you to achieve your goal. Update your question again if you stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parser in JAVA to parse the XML document. The package in java for this purpose is `javax.xml.parsers` . `DocumentBuilder` parses XML into a `Document` and `Document` is a tree structured data structure that is DOM(Document Object Model) readable file. Its nodes can be traversed/ changed/ accessed by DOM methods.

Here is a very good tutorial on XML DOM: http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/

and more specifically: http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/accessing-xml-file-java.shtml

also you can always refer to w3school for more theory on DOM!